# Confidence in sample mean, given sample variance?

Tags: standard-deviation, variance, confidence-interval

Let's say that I have an large population of data, but that I have a sample mean and sample variance calculated from a subset of that data.

Can I use my sample variance (or standard deviation) to know how confident I should be in my sample mean being close to the population mean?

It seems like I should because a low variance seems to indicate that there isn't very far that the mean could move, but on the other hand, taking more samples isn't going to make the variance approach zero.

Is there some other calculation I should be using for getting a confidence amount in my sample mean?

Comment: Do you know anything about the underlying distribution? When sampling from a normal distribution for example, you can create confidence intervals based on the mean, the sample variance and the number of observations.

Comment: I don't know anything about the distribution no, other than observing the shape that my samples form hehe.

Comment: It turns out that the central limit theorem makes my data a normal distribution because I'm taking unbiased samples.  Sorry, not a lot of exp in this area of math (:

Comment: It makes your mean approximately normally distributed, but you also need $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2$ to follow a chi squared distribution to construct the confidence interval that is typically used for normal distributions. Maybe bootstrapping can help you, but I'll leave that to the experts :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look carefully at the construction of a confidence interval:

$$ \mu +/- Z_{\alpha} * \sqrt{VAR(\mu)} $$

$$ VAR[\mu] = VAR[\sum{x_i}/n]  = n * VAR[ {x_i}/n] = VAR[X] / n  $$

so you just have to divide the variation of the sample by the number of observations that were made.

hope this helps!